# Updating object in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I can't figure out how to make a javascript function to update the "checked" value inside the object in an array like this

```
array:[
  { id:1,
    name:"foo"
    options: [
      {id:"one", checked: false},
      {id:"two", checked: true}
    ]
  },
  { id:2,
    name:"faa"
    options: [
      {id:"one", checked: false},
      {id:"two", checked: true}
    ]
  }
 ]
```

I know how to do it with array of objects but am stuck with this. Any suggestions into what I need to do?
Thanks

Update typo in array format

Comment: What have you tried to do?

Comment: I have tried using map, but the nested array got me confused a bit. Thanks everyone for the help. I will accept the answer that best suits my question. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly. you want to update the `checked` property via checkbox in HTML template.

**Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    array: [{
        id:1,
        name:"foo",
        options: [
        {id:"one", checked: false},
        {id:"two", checked: true}]
    }, {
        id:2,
        name:"faa",
        options: [
        {id:"one", checked: false},
        {id:"two", checked: true}]
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="data in array" :key="data.id">
    <b>{{ data.name }}</b>
    <div v-for="(checkboxData, index) in data.options" :key="index">
      {{ checkboxData.id }} : <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkboxData.checked"/>
    </div>
  </div><br>
  <b>Updated Value : </b>
  <p>{{ array }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, yes that is what I am trying to do. This is very helpful, thank you.

Comment: Glad that it helps!. Please mark it as accept so that it will be helpful for other developers as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map()` to create a new array of objects with the updated values.

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "foo",
    options: [
      { id: "one", checked: false },
      { id: "two", checked: true }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "faa",
    options: [
      { id: "one", checked: false },
      { id: "two", checked: true }
    ]
  }
];

const result = data.map((d) => {
  return {
    ...d,
    options: d.options.map((o) => {
      return {
        ...o,
        checked: !o.checked // for example invert the checked value
      }
    })
  }
});

console.log(result);
```